# Good Booking Engines Suggestions

Tags: scripting, website, open-source

I want to get some suggestion for a Customizable/Opensource Booking Engine for Hotels That you've used or had coded them. The booking engine I'm looking for is the one you can add and customize their fields (address,rates, and other stuffs). Also I can easily integrate it to my existing site. I was looking at CultBooking but I've been having hard time understanding their interface and documentation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used any of these, but there are a (surprisingly) large number of packages available for this on freshmeat:

http://freshmeat.net/search?q=hotel&submit=Search